# How can I create jsp page in springboot project?

Tags: spring-boot, project

I have spring boot project in IntelliJ IDEA by maven and when I want create jsp page like name"index.jsp" it being disable and not active as jsp page please help.
How can I solve that problem?

Comment: Refer https://www.javacodegeeks.com/2018/03/spring-boot-jsp.html

Answer (score 0):

inside /src/main/resources/application.properties (if you dont have this file craete it)
append the following:

```
spring.mvc.view.prefix: /WEB-INF/jsp/
spring.mvc.view.suffix: .jsp
```

please note your jsp must be inside WEB-INFF/jsp/ folder, if you want it in another folder just change the value of this property

Comment: i have created WEB-INF/jsp folder and appended prefix,suffix. but IntelliJ does not know just 'index' name

Comment: Can you please share in your question the code example? and a small screen shot of how your workspace looks like? it will be easier to me to answer you